# Planar discrete dynamical systems' omega limit sets

Tags: asymptotics, dynamical-systems, discrete-time

This is just curiosity. Given a discrete time dynamical system $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ on the plane, $f:X\rightarrow X$ for $X$ a (relatively) compact region of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $f$ continuous on $X$. Suppose we know that an orbit has the property that its omega-limit set is compact, non-empty and contains no fixed point. Is it possible to conclude anything along the lines of Poincare'-Bendixon theorem (that is something like: then the omega limit set must be an orbit itself etc...)? I have searched a while but it seems that Poincare'-Bendixon theory in general really does not apply to discrete dynamical systems. Are there any close/weaker results to a situation as the above anyone happens to know about? Note: I have not assumed that the omega-limit set has finitely many points. Otherwise many things could be said about such omega-limit set (at least in the compact case).

Comment: Take a rotation with a non-commensurable angle, that is, the angle is an irrational multiple of $\pi$. Then the orbit is dense on a circle, without any fixed points.

Comment: I am aware of this example, but I am looking for something genuinely 2D. In a sense, there are many 1D situations in the literature that show very little can be said. If I am not mistaken you can see irrational rotations of the circle as 1D (just use R/Z or mod1 identifications) dynamical system. The planar system and the reduced 1D one are topologically conjugate, I mean.